# "rails generate integration_test static_pages" ROR tutorial Chapter 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux

I don't know why every time I tried to enter this command

Users@ubuntu:~/rails_projects/sample_app$ **rails generate integration_test static_pages**

It has problem like

```
/home/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:229:in `default_controller_and_action': missing :controller (ArgumentError)

from /home/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:116:in `normalize_options!'

from /home/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:64:in `initialize'

from /home/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1438:in `new'

from /home/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1438:in `add_route'

from /home/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1417:in `decomposed_match'

from /home/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:45:in `top (required)'

from bin/rails:4:in `require'

from bin/rails:4:in `main'
```

Also when I enter "bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb", it has problem too.
Even the "require" command, it will show "require : command not found"

Anybody who can help me a little bit?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have your `static_pages_controller`?

Comment: I added it manually under /spec/requests